Outlook Inquiry: When moving emails to sub-folders, have them be marked as read
Ideally, I would love it when I move emails into any of my created sub-folder, emails will automatically be marked as read.
I have no experience creating rules or doing any similar function in Outlook, so please explain as if talking to an Outlook beginner.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here is a step-by-step guide to create a rule in Outlook that will automatically mark emails as read when you move them to a sub-folder:

Open Outlook and navigate to the Home tab.
Click on Rules and select Manage Rules & Alerts.
Click on New Rule to start creating a new rule.
In the Rules Wizard, select Apply rule on messages I receive
and click Next.
Set the conditions that apply to the emails you want
to move. For example, you can set conditions based on the sender,
recipient, or keywords in the subject line.
Select the action to move the emails to a specific folder. Choose the folder where you want the emails to be moved.
Add another action to mark the emails as read. Click on Add Action and select mark it as read.
Click Finish to save the rule.

This will ensure that any emails meeting the specified conditions will be moved to the selected folder and marked as read automatically.
More information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-in-outlook-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59#PickTab=Classic_Outlook
